# r does not allow 100 iterations in my while() loop

Tags: r, string, while-loop, readline

I'm creating simulation data using R-studio. I have a while loop as follows:

```
play <- function(){
  #game number
  i <- 0
  iterations <- readline("How many iterations would you like?:")
   while(i<iterations) { 
    my_simulation()
    i<-i+1
}
```

When you enter `99`, it runs 99 simulations. When I enter `100`, it just runs 2.

What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading the input as character. Just wrap `iterations` with `as.integer`:

```
play <- function(){
  #game number
  i <- 0
  iterations <- readline("How many iterations would you like?:")
   while(i < as.integer(iterations)) { 
    my_simulation()
    i <- i + 1
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why? Setting it to `0` gives nothing, but `00` (or more 0s) gives you one result, so `100` yields 2, `200` yields 3, and so on, but under 100 it treats it as an actual integer?

Comment: Good find! This shows that the conditional `i<iterations` is doing an alphabetic comparison, not a numeric. For examples, see `1<'99'`, `2<'100'`, `11<'9'`. R is silently coercing the class of both sides to the highest "class", `logical < integer < numeric < character`, so `11` is internally tested as `"11"`, and since the first character `"1"` is less than the first of the RHS `"9"`, it is less. As soon as the RHS becomes `"100"`, when `i` is 1, then `! "1" < "1"`.

Comment: @r2evans is right, you are reading the input of type character and applying an alphabetic comparison. You should be always careful with types when dealing with user inputs, especially within the Shiny framework.

Comment: Excellent answer and discussion to my question. Thanks!